# Math expression in IF clause with Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I want to use math expression in IF clause - something like this:

```
         #!/bin/sh

         now=`date +%H%M`

         if [ $now % 5 -gt 0 ] ; then
           exit
         fi

         perl ...
```

What is a correct **syntax** for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if expr $now % 5 \> 0 > /dev/null; then ...
```

or

```
if test $(( $now % 5 )) -gt 0; then ...
```

Note that you do not really need an if clause at all, and you could do

```
test $(( $now % 5 )) -gt 0 && exit
```

Comment: Anything more simple with less resources?

Comment: What do you mean by "less resources"?  expr is builtin in most shells, but you could do: test $(( $now % 5 )) -gt 0

Comment: This >> $((now % 5)) -gt 0 << or this >> $(($now % 5)) -gt 0 << ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash:

```
if (( now%5 > 0 )); then ...
```

Comment: I don't know where it's documented, but inside `(())` you don't require the `$` for simple variables.

Comment: Please take note of glenn's first sentence!  This syntax works in bash but is not supported in all shells.